# confusion about function minimization nomenclature

Tags: optimization, partial-derivative

I am confused about meaning of the following :

$$\underset{y}{\text{min}} f(x,y) $$

and how to solve for it? I initially thought it meant $\min f(x,y)$ subject to $y=y_o$ for various $y_o$ but don't think that's the case. Does this need all the points $(x,y)$ where :

$$ \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} =0  $$

and

$$ \frac{\partial ^2f(x,y)}{\partial^2 y} >0.$$

Some related discussion is here:
[Max Min of function less than Min max of function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186697/max-min-of-function-less-than-min-max-of-function)

Comment: It means minimize $f(x,y)$ over $y$ (taking $x$ to be a given constant). So yes, what you said in the second half.

Comment: I am mentioning a link above, In one of the answers (by Belov), the definition does not match yours as it says that $min_y f(x,y) $ is a function of x. But i am not clear about that either.

Comment: Sure it matches. If you fix $x$ and minimize $f(x,y)$ over all $y$ you get some value. If you choose a different $x$ you get a different value. In that sense the result of $\min_y f(x,y)$ is a function of the value of $x$.

Comment: yup, thats what i was also thinking. thanks for confirming.